# Cycles diffuse baking gives only black results with different settings

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, baking

Ok so heres a weird problem I have. I try to bake a diffuse map from photoscan and it always gives black results no matter what settings I tweak. Ive tried with and without global light with sun without it Ive tried to combine with Principled BSDF and without it, with Diffuse BSDF and without. Ive tried to tweak emissions and Subsurface parameters rougness etc.

Nothing works or gives any different results than just black texture. Only thing that changes anything is output margin px size. outline seems to change properly. So whole image isnt black just the UV part of it. So it must be the light problem but with varying settings of it doesnt change the results whats the problem im running out of options. And yes i've tried to bake without cage also with different parameters there too.

[image]

Comment: Have you made sure your normals are pointing outside?

Comment: i did check normals quite a few times and did auto recalculation, did check manually also  they point outwards like they should